# Django Get Returns More then one value

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

hello im new to django i am making a blog site i am getting an error when i try to acces my blog
my code:
views.py:

```
from django.http import request
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from .models import Item, Blog

# Create your views here.
class BlogView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = "main/blog.html"
    context_object_name = "blog"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context =  super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        search_input = self.request.GET.get('search') or ''
        if search_input:
            context['blog'] = context['blog'].filter(title__icontains=search_input)
        return context


class Detail(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "main/item.html"
    context_object_name = "items"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context =  super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        obj = Item.objects.get()
        context['items'] = Item.objects.filter(blog_id=obj.blog_id)
        return context
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
    
    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ""
        return url
        
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ""
        return url
```

any help would be appreciated on this error:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /detail/2/
get() returned more than one Item -- it returned 2!
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:5000/detail/2/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned
Exception Value:    
get() returned more than one Item -- it returned 2!
Exception Location: /home/moeez/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py, line 439, in get
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/moeez/Python Projects/blogsite',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/moeez/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.2.0.dev0-py3.8.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/virtualenv-20.4.3-py3.8.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.1-py3.8.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/filelock-3.0.12-py3.8.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/distlib-0.3.1-py3.8.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/appdirs-1.4.4-py3.8.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 12 May 2021 14:31:09 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `Item.objects.get()` with no arguments. You should use `get` the same way as `filter`, but `get` may return **only one object**, and `filter` may return a queryset.

For example:

```
obj = Item.objects.get(id=some_id)
```

Comment: how do i get the id

Comment: As you passed the id of `2` in the url, you probably want that one right? Print your **kwargs on terminal and take a look, it should be there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should use lookups that are guaranteed unique while using get method, such as the primary key or fields in a unique constraint if get() method returns more than one object, it raises a Model.**MultipleObjectsReturned** exception as in your case here **Item.objects.get()** finds more than 1 object and it raises an exception.

To handle this problem pass the pk captured from url to get method.You can access the same from kwargs dictionary with key named as 'pk'.

Change line in your code:

```
obj = Item.objects.get()
```

To :

```
obj = Item.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```